# How to unfreeze / prevent freeze on a property of a dynamic created object with a style?

Tags: c#, xaml

In my XAML I got a `Style` I use to attach to dynamically created `Path` objects:

```
    <Style x:Key="styleBladePiece" TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
        <Setter Property="Data" Value="..." />
        <Setter Property="Fill">
            <Setter.Value>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource BladeFillColor1}" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

In my code behind I create a lot of them like so:

```
    Path pathBladePiece = new Path();
    pathBladePiece.Style = (Style)this.FindResource("styleBladePiece");
```

Now on a later step I try to animate the `Color` of the `Fill` property of the `Path` object, like so:

```
    ColorAnimation a = new ColorAnimation();
    a.Duration = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 400));
    a.To = (Color)this.FindResource("BladeFillColor2");
    pathBladePiece.Fill.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, a);
```

But it turns out the `Fill` property is frozen to that time. 
In the designer as well as on runtime I get: `InvalidOperationException: property "Color" on "System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush" can not be animated, because the object is sealed or locked.`

When debugging XDecProc.exe: `A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.Expression.Markup.DocumentModel.StatePersistingException' occurred in Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.dll" when debugging the designer.`

Can I unfreeze it or prevent it to be frozen?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Shared="False"`, from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778.aspx)

> Another scenario for x:Shared="false" is if you use a Freezable resource for animation values but want to modify the resource on a per animation basis

Define `SolidBrush` as resource

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BladeFillBrush1" x:Shared="False" Color="{StaticResource BladeFillColor1}"/>
```

and then

```
<Style x:Key="styleBladePiece" TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource BladeFillBrush1}">
</Style>
```

Comment: My bad, not for style, but for `BladeFillColor1`.

Comment: So I tried `<Color x:Shared="False" x:Key="BladeFillColor1">#FF767676</Color>` in my resources or `<SolidColorBrush x:Shared="False" Color="{StaticResource BladeFillColor1}" />` on my control XAML. The first keeps the problem, the 2nd throws a XAML syntax exception.